# Kafka round-robin distribution strategy not working

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm new to Kafka.
Kafka Producer isn't distributing my messages in round-robin but sending all my messages to the same partition **although I haven't set any key**.
Sharing the producer code and output below.
[kafka logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNG50.png)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProducerDemoWithCallback.class);

    //create producer properties
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"127.0.0.1:9092");
    properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class.getName());

    //create producer
    KafkaProducer<String,String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);

    for( int i=0;i<5;i++) {

        //Producer Record
        final ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>("Topic-A", "test" + Integer.toString(i));

        //send data
        producer.send(record, new Callback() {
            public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    logger.info("Recieved new metadata: \n" +
                            "Topic : " + recordMetadata.topic() + "\n" +
                            "Partition : " + recordMetadata.partition() + "\n" +
                            "Offsets : " + recordMetadata.offset() + "\n" +
                            "Timestamp : " + recordMetadata.timestamp());
                } else {
                    logger.error("error : " + e);
                }
            }
        });

    }

        producer.flush();

        producer.close();



}
```

Comment: Can you try with more values producing to the topic? When only writing 5 records in a short amount of time chances are high that they all get into the same batch and therefore end up in the same partition of the topic.

Comment: Hello mike, thanks for replying. I tried of producing 100 records to the topic...but still all the values are going to the same partition

Comment: I guess we need more data ;-) try setting the producer config `batch.size` to 0 and repeat sending.

Comment: I'm following the same tutorial as the OP and faced the same dilemma. In order to see a different partition you need to change the value to 10000(as the topic from tutorial has 3 partitions).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a little bit too late, but maybe someone could find this useful:

In the example provided by the OP, you need to add a Thread.Sleep(1000) before sending another message. This is due the Sticky Partitioning strategy Kafka has.

Also it's very important that you only create the Producer once and use it to send all the messages. If not, the round robin won't work either

See:
[Why is Kafka distribution over partitions far from even when no key is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68316183/why-is-kafka-distribution-over-partitions-far-from-even-when-no-key-is-used)
https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/1346

I know this is for .NET, but I'm pretty sure this could also be the case in Java