# Round Robin message assignment to partition not working for messages without key in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, apache-kafka, microservices

Trying to send messages to all the partition in round-robin fashion but all the messages are going into the last partition. Can anyone please help me with that?

I am using **Confluent.Kafka** nuget package. My producer Configuration -

```
"ProducerConfiguration": {
        "bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092"
      }
```

And my Kafka producer class -

```
public class Publisher
    {

        private ProducerConfig _producerConfig;
        public Publisher(IOptions<ApplicationSetting> _applicationSetting)
        {
            var producerConfig = _applicationSetting.Value.KafkaConfiguration.ProducerConfiguration;
            _producerConfig = new ProducerConfig(producerConfig);
        }

        public async Task<DeliveryResult<Null, TValue>> Publish<TValue>(TValue message, string topic = null)
        {
            using var producer = new ProducerBuilder<Null, TValue>(_producerConfig)
               .SetValueSerializer(new JsonSerializer<TValue>())
               .Build();
            var topicName = String.IsNullOrEmpty(topic) ? message.GetType().Name : topic;
            return await producer.ProduceAsync(topicName, new Message<Null, TValue>() { Value = message });
        }
    }
```

Publishing the message like -

```
public class DemoHandler : IRequestHandler<SendMail, string>
    {

        private readonly Publisher _publisher;

        public DemoHandler(Publisher publisher)
        {
            _publisher = publisher;
        }
        public async Task<string> Handle(SendMail message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await _publisher.Publish(message);
            return "Message sent";
        }
    }
```

All the messages are going to the last partition only -
[image: Check it in this image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you try sent more data to the topic after some time? It could have happened that those 5 messages were batched together by the producer and then send to the one partition (in your case the last partition).

Comment: @mike I tried to send more data after 10 mins. In this case, also all the data is going to the last partition.

Answer (score 0):

I added this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71791802/628908

I faced this same issue. In this case the issue will be because you're re-creating a new IProducer instance each time you call your `Publish` method

If you could make sure the IProducer instance is the same every time you call `Publish`, that will let the producer to decide which partition send the message to.