# Why is Kafka distribution over partitions far from even when no key is used?

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka

I'm trying to get my head around Kafka. One of the Hello World-like apps I've made is where a Producer doesn't use a key with the messages. All the documentation and tutorials say that the messages should be spread over the consumers in a round-robin fashion, but my tests show otherwise. It uses the default sample solution in Visual Studio (with the weather forecasts). Everytime the API is queried, the generated forecasts are also published to Kafka.

The producer is nothing more than the following, in an API controller class (every time this is called, there are 5 weather forecasts in the array):

```
ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig
{
    BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
    ClientId = $"KafkaResearch-{Dns.GetHostName()}"
};

using (IProducer<string, string> producer = new ProducerBuilder<string, string>(config).Build())
{
    foreach (var forecast in weatherForecasts)
    {
        string value = JsonSerializer.Serialize(forecast);
        Message<string, string> message = new Message<string, string> { Value = value };
    
        producer.Produce("weather-forecasts", message, DeliveryHandler);
    }
    producer.Flush();
}
```

The messages are all different. They contain randomly generated data, every time:

```
weatherForecasts = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
{
    Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(index),
    TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
    Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
})
.ToArray();
```

The consumer is a very simple console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to abort");

    var config = new ConsumerConfig
    {
        BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
        GroupId = "foo",
        AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Latest                
    };

    using (var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<string, string>(config).Build())
    {
        consumer.Subscribe("weather-forecasts");

        while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            var consumeResult = consumer.Consume(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

            if (consumeResult != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Message received on partition {consumeResult.Partition}, key: {consumeResult.Message.Key ?? "<--null-->"}");
                Console.WriteLine($"  {consumeResult.Message.Value}");
            }
        }

        consumer.Close();
    }
}
```

The topic is created with 12 partitions:

```
kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:9092  --create --partitions 12 --topic weather-forecasts
```

When I spam the API with a browser I would expect a (sort of) equal distribution over the partitions, but it is far from that. Only 4 out of 12 partitions get messages, so when using 5 consumers, one of them is idle.

If I send all the weather forecasts in an array in one message (so without the `foreach` in the producer) all messages are assigned to the same partition, every single time.

As requested in the comments: the code looks like this then:

```
ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig
{
    BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
    ClientId = $"KafkaResearch-{Dns.GetHostName()}"
};

using (IProducer<string, string> producer = new ProducerBuilder<string, string>(config).Build())
{
    string value = JsonSerializer.Serialize(weatherForecasts);

    Message<string, string> message = new Message<string, string> { Value = value };
    producer.Produce("weather-forecasts", message, DeliveryHandler);
    producer.Flush();
}
```

When I add a random key to the message, the distribution over all the consumer is pretty good.

I've tried specifying a `Partitioner` in the `ProducerConfig`. That changes to which partition the message is assigned, but still produces only to very few partitions (bonus question: why is the Partitioner a setting on the Producer instead of the topic? I'd expect that all producers have to use the same method for partitioning...).

```
kafka-topics --version
2.7.1 (Commit:61dbce85d0d41457)
```

Using Confluent.Kafka Nuget package (by Confluent Inc., Andreas Heider) version 1.5.3

Thanks for any insights,

Quido.

Comment: The array contains 5 different weather forecasts that get generated every time. Every weather forecast contains a random temperature (-20 .. 55 C) and a random summary (one of ten strings). So every message should be different. But even if not, the message itself is not used in partitioning, is it?

Comment: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/1346 - I suspect the issue is that the producer is correctly doing round robin - but you keep spinning up new producers. Does it work if you use just one producer?

Comment: @mjwills Refactored it to re-use the same producer every time (AddSingleton using Core's DI). Works now. Apparently "random" is pretty deterministic if you recreate the producer...
If you put your comment in an answer I'll accept it.
I think it's a bug in the producer, though. For performance reasons you want to re-use the producer and not create it every time, but random should be random.

Comment: Note that "round robin" and "random" are very much not the same thing. Where did you get the idea it would be _random_?

Comment: `(bonus question: why is the Partitioner a setting on the Producer instead of the topic?` Because 95% of the time you will be using a singleton producer and a standardised partitioning system. If you don't want that you can do that, but you'll need more than one producer.

Comment: @mjwills: I got the idea for random from the default partitioner name: consistent_random. Obviously you're right: random is not round robin.
And on the bonus question: I would expect that you want a standardized partitioning system for a topic: every producer needs to use the same partitioning system, otherwise  one key could be assigned to different partitions by two different producers (defeating the purpose of keys). Making the partitioning system a setting on the topic instead of the producer would guarantee that all producers use the same system.

Comment: `otherwise one key could be assigned to different partitions by two different producers` You chose something with `random` in the name. That is part of the agreement. ;) If you want consistent, you need to specify a key and use `consistent` instead. `Making the partitioning system a setting on the topic instead of the producer would guarantee that all producers use the same system.` I hear what you mean, but it just doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `Producer` does the round robin work, and you aren't reusing the same `Producer` (you keep `new`ing up multiple ones).

So you need to use the `Producer` as a singleton to make the round robin logic useful. See also https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/1346 .